# IPv6 nameservers but no AAAA record?

Tags: ipv6

I'm trying to understand the network I'm part of. It has a couple thousand computers and the backbone routers are supposed to be IPv6, but the firewalls are not, thus there is a hypothetical IPv6 capability, but no routing is possible. I talked to a network admin and he said it had something to do with the firewalls not being IPv6 capable or not routing as fast with IPv6. Does anyone know what firewalls (I don't know anything more specific than that) can have to do with a local network and IPv6?

When I dig the domain of my organization (when I'm in the local network), I get DNS records which also include AAAA records for the nameservers (I don't see these AAAA records when I google the DNS records for the site). But there is no IPv6 routing possible and the host itself does not have a AAAA records. Do you know what are things organizations need to do to migrate their servers to IPv6? Do you need to change any hardware to make this possible if the routers already support IPv6?

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 is an entirely different IP stack from IPv4.  Various things are simpler in IPv6 than IPv4, and vice versa.

IPv6 has a site local address space which has been deprecated.  I think this was intended to be similar the private address spaces in IPv4.

Many ISPs do not yet support IPv6 so tunneling may be required.  A lot of older (not necessarily that old) equipment is not capable of working with IPv6.  This may include some (a few, many, most, or all) of the routers your organization uses.

Many networks will have internal firewalls between various segments.  If these firewalls are not IPv6 capable any inter-segment IPv6 routing would need to be tunneled.

If the routers do support IPv6 internal routing within firewalled segments should be possible.  However, device discovery will likely depend on DNS or other host registries.  Finding unregistered hosts in an IPv6 network can be much more difficult with IPv6 than it is with IPv4 where range scans are practical.